# Handling new fields when merging in data using hashbytes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We load in data from stage into our ODS and check for differences using hashbytes. We calculate hashbytes from the stage tables and insert/update into the destination table and also store the hashbytes value in the destination.

The problem arises when there's a new field that we need to bring in from a source system. We'll add a new column in the ODS table with a default value but the calculated hashbytes are different because of this new field. As a result, everything gets updated even if nothing has changed. We'd have to update Hashbytes column in the large (300M but could be 1B rows) table whenever we add a new field which is not often but enough to be cumbersome.

What are the best approaches to handle this?

I'm thinking remove the hashbytes column from the ODS table and just calculate it in the proc for stage and ODS values. I inherited this code so I don't know why the hashbytes is stored in the ODS table, is that a best practice?

**Approach #1**

```
UPDATE b
SET Field1 = a.Field1
    ,Field2 = a.Field2
FROM source a 
INNER JOIN destination b ON a.PrimaryKeyField = b.PrimaryKeyField
WHERE CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONCAT(a.[Field1], '|', a.[Field2])
    <> CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONCAT(b.[Field1], '|', b.[Field2])
```

**Approach #2**

```
UPDATE b
SET Field1 = a.Field1
    ,Field2 = a.Field2
FROM source a 
INNER JOIN destination b ON a.PrimaryKeyField = b.PrimaryKeyField
WHERE  (a.Field1 <> b.Field1
    OR isnull(a.Field2,'') <> isnull(b.Field2,''))
```

Comment: @RandolphWest About a million rows in stage. ODS is about 300M. There are indexes on the primary key so I think performance should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to give you an answer without knowing your data.

My guesses is: [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) returns 20 bytes, the developer wanted to avoid comparing very long strings. In my opinion this is not a great reason, because the SHA1s are generated on the fly, so I seriously doubt there is a performance gain.

If strings are sensibly longer than hashes and they never/rarely change, consider storing the hashes in a generated field.

Also, you may want to check the [CHECKSUM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [BINARY_CHECKSUM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions. They're fast enough, and they ignore certain differences between strings, which is usually what one wants. More info [here](https://sql-bits.com/sql-server-checksum-vs-checksum_binary-vs-hashbytes/)